# Is my issue with my code or is it the ONLINE compiler

Tags: c#

Currently I am using the website compile c# online - http://rextester.com/ to compile my code. I am unable to use visual studio for now, although I will be able to use it soon and I will test my code there. I was trying to make a doppler effect calculator. Being a beginner at C#, I wanted to try to make a simple circumference calculator where you select circumference calculator, enter a radius and get a circumference. Although when trying to run my code I get the answer that the process had been killed because it had exceeded resources.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string calcType = Console.ReadLine();
            float pi = 6.28f;
            float radius = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            float circumference = pi * radius;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Calculator Type. Type circumference for circumference calculator");
            if(calcType == "circumference"){
                Console.WriteLine("Now enter a radius");
                circumference = pi * radius;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(circumference);                
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler just says working. No console error. If there is a problem in my code, help would be greatly appreciated, although I will be able to resume to visual studio if there is an issue with online compilers.
Thank You.
P.S: Running on Mac for now.

Comment: You'll have to try it in a "real" compiler to know. Asking Stack Overflow to do this for you is off-topic.

Comment: probably your online compiler has no enough resources to service your program...

Comment: Go download LinqPad and run it in there.

Comment: It has certainly nothing to do with your program!

Comment: Also because you are using `Console.ReadLine()` you need to pre-fill the input tet box before you run the app.

Comment: What do you mean @DavidG

Comment: Thank you for the tip Il'l try LinqPad too!